# A way to write derivatives

Tags: derivatives, notation, soft-question

There are many notations when it comes to derivatives such as $f'(x)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$. As of the moment, I can't find a reference that uses $dy/dx$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Is it acceptable to write $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $dy/dx$ or not?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I think it's completely unacceptable as it reinforces the idea that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is got by dividing $dy$ by $dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $dy/dx$ is much the same as writing $\frac{3}{5}$ as $3/5$. There is no mathematical difference between the two notations—only a typographical one.

Comment: What if it is $\dfrac{d^{2}u}{dx\,dy}$? Do I write it as $(d^{2}u)/(dx\,dy)$?

Comment: It's not clear to me what $\frac{d^2u}{dxdy}$ even means. Regardless, it is always acceptable to indicate division using a slash instead of a fraction bar. Even though $dy/dx$ is not really a fraction, we adopt the same typographical convention as we do for the quotient of two numbers.

Comment: What I mean is like $\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)$.

Comment: @soupless: For more complicated expressions, it is better style to use a horizontal bar than a slash. But the *meaning* of those expressions is the same.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you please leave it here? I really find it useful.

Comment: @soupless: To summarise, there is no problem with writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $dy/dx$, so long as you remember that $dy/dx$ is not a ratio—rather, it is the limit of a ratio. If you want more information about *that*, then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio).

Answer (score -2):

Writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $dy/dx$ is a matter of choice, mathematical speaking they are both ratios, so I can even write as $[ dy : dx ]$

But when compiling a good math text, in textbooks or some type-settings, it's better to write as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because it looks more like function than variable

Also consider when we want to write higher derivatives
$$\frac{d^7y}{dx^7}$$
$$d^7y/dx^7$$
vote to choose

Comment: As cited by @Joe, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a ratio, though in some cases, it can be treated as if it is a ratio.